# How to disable javascript in chrome programmatically

Tags: c#

Is it possible to turn off JavaScript within Chrome using a Windows application. 
I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Is there any possible way to do it.

Comment: http://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-enable-or-disable-javascript

Comment: i dont find the application folder in chrome...

Comment: You have to specify that no JavaScript should be allowed when first starting chrome via the command line switch as above.

Comment: it doesnt work on windows 10.

Comment: I don't think Google would appreciate you programmatically hacking and breaking their software. Or was there some kind of scope to the question I didn't realize.

Comment: 1) Hack Google GIT repo 2) Commit code change to remove V8 from Chrome 3) Init a build 4) Deploy update on Google servers to every PC in the world 5) Profit

Comment: then what about the Java Script switcher extension, will they also doing the same thing.....

Comment: @AnoopMishra using "a chrome extension" and using "a windows application" are different things... if you want to make a Chrome Extension, then yes, it can be done, but that's not what you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done with current versions [because browser hijacking is actually a problem](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/03/protecting-user-settings-on-windows.html).

If you want to disable Javascript for your Windows organization, you can do so via Group Policies... there are [ADM/ADMX administrative templates](http://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip) for the settings, which you can distribute via Active Directory or using the local policies in Windows: save the templates to `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions` and configure them using the local group policy editor (run `gpedit.msc`).

Other way would be making a Chrome extension and use the settings API, using javascript. You could easily add exceptions to all current tabs, but I'm pretty sure that you don't want that (you'd use `chrome.contentSettings.javascript.set` and set exceptions for all urls when a tab is open)

Answer (score 2):

For current chrome (ver. 57), using `--user-data-dir` command line switch:

- `chrome --user-data-dir=my_dir`
- Close chrome
- There is a file Preferences in `my_dir/Default/` with JSON content. Add/change 
  `"default_content_setting_values":{"javascript":2}` to key `"profile"`.
- `chrome --user-data-dir=my_dir` again, with Javascript disabled.

Python 2.7 code:

```
import subprocess
import json

data_dir = r'h:\my-data-dir'
cmd = [r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", r"--user-data-dir=%s" % data_dir]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
p.kill()

preferences_path = '%s/Default/Preferences' % data_dir
json_object = None
with open(preferences_path, 'r') as f:
    json_object = json.loads(f.readline())
    json_object['profile']['default_content_setting_values'] = {'javascript': 2}
with open(preferences_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(json_object))

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) # javascript disabled here
```